# On Click Command

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a quiz for my class that will allow the user to take a quiz but only in turtle graphics, so the quiz question will appear in the turtle graphics screen and they will choose which answer they want by pressing the part of the screen labeled a, b, c, or d. The issue I'm having is, is that I don't know how to have a new question appear when the user picks their choice and I don't know how turtle.listen works. Any ideas?

This is what I have so far:

```
import time
import turtle

x = turtle.xcor()
y = turtle.ycor()
Slytherin = 0
Griffindor = 0 
Hufflepuff = 0
Ravenclaw = 0 

def introduction():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(10,150)
    turtle.write("\n This code is a quiz that will determine what Hogwart house you belong in:\n Slytherin, Griffindor, Hufflepuff, or Ravenclaw! \n  \n You will be asked quiz questions on this screen, and then \n when you want to answer, you tell the program \n what you chose by pressing the corresponding section. \n", align = "center" , font=("Arial", 20, "normal")) 

def user_interface():
    turtle.setup(700, 700)
    turtle.screensize(700, 700)
    turtle.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, 500, 500)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(125, 180)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setpos(125, 0)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(62.5, 90)
    turtle.write("a", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
    turtle.setpos(250, 0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setpos(250, 180)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(187.5, 90)
    turtle.write("b", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
    turtle.setpos(375, 0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setpos(375, 180)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(312.5, 90)
    turtle.write("c", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
    turtle.setpos(437.5, 90)
    turtle.write("d", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
    turtle.setpos(0,180)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setpos(500, 180)

def shapedrawer(x, y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    #First Column
    if x <= 125 and 0 <= y <= 180: 
        turtle.color("green")
        turtle.circle(10)
        Slytherin += 1
    #Second Column
    elif 125 < x <= 250 and 0 <= y <= 180: 
        turtle.color("red")
        turtle.circle(10)
        Griffindor += 1 
    #Third Column
    elif 250 < x <= 375 and 0 <= y <= 180:
        turtle.color("purple")
        turtle.circle(10) 
        Hufflepuff += 1
    #Fourth Column
    elif 375 < x <= 500 and 0 <= y <= 180:
        turtle.color("blue")
        turtle.circle(10)
        Ravenclaw += 1
    turtle.end_fill()


def candy_question():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(100, 350)
    turtle.write("What is your favorite type of candy? \n a. Bertie Bott's Every Flavour Beans \n b. Honeydukes Sherbet Lemons \n c. Chocolate Frogs \n d. Candy Floss", font=("Arial", 20, "normal"))

def pet_question():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(170, 250)
    turtle.write("Which is animal would you prefer as a pet? \n a. A lizard \n b. A cat \n c. A dog \n d. A ferret", font=("Arial", 20, "normal"))

def class_question(): 
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(170, 350)
    turtle.write("Which is your favorite class?  \n b. Potions \n a. Charms \n c. History of Magic \n d. Transfiguration", font=("Arial", 20, "normal"))

def color_question():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(170, 350)
    turtle.write("Pick your favorite color \n a. Blue \n b. Purple \n c. White \n d. Orange", font=("Arial", 20, "normal"))

def life_question(): 
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(130, 350)
    turtle.write("If you could only do one thing for the rest \n of your life what would you do? \n a. Explore the World \n b. Start your own company \n c. Stay in school forever \n d. I don't know", font=("Arial", 20, "normal"))

def vacation_question():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(200, 150)
    turtle.write("If you were going on a vacation, you would go to... \n a. London \n b. The wilderness \n c. Home, to your family \n d. The beach", font=("Arial", 20, "normal"))


def main_loop(x,y):
    introduction()
    time.sleep(5)
    user_interface()
    turtle.onscreenclick(shapedrawer)
    pet_question()
    turtle.listen()
    while turtle.onclick(x) == 0 < x < 125:
    turtle.clear()
    candy_question()

main_loop(x,y)
turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using events, you turn over control to turtle's event handler and you can no longer determine ahead of time when questions are asked.

The solution is to create a list of questions (a list of question functions in this case) and have `shapedrawer()` fire off the next question after the previous one gets answered:

```
import time
import turtle

turtle.setup(700, 700)
turtle.screensize(700, 700)
turtle.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, 500, 500)

TEXTFONT = ("Arial", 20, "normal")
QUIZFONT = ("Arial", 40, "normal")

Slytherin = 0
Griffindor = 0
Hufflepuff = 0
Ravenclaw = 0

def introduction():
    marker_turtle.penup()
    marker_turtle.goto(250, 200)
    marker_turtle.write("""
This code is a quiz that will determine what Hogwart house you
belong in: Slytherin, Griffindor, Hufflepuff, or Ravenclaw!

You will be asked quiz questions on this screen, and
then when you want to answer, you tell the program
what you chose by pressing the corresponding section
""", align="center", font=TEXTFONT)

def user_interface():
    turtle.penup()

    turtle.setpos(62.5, 90)
    turtle.write("a", font=QUIZFONT)
    turtle.setpos(125, 180)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setpos(125, 0)
    turtle.penup()

    turtle.setpos(187.5, 90)
    turtle.write("b", font=QUIZFONT)
    turtle.setpos(250, 0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setpos(250, 180)
    turtle.penup()

    turtle.setpos(312.5, 90)
    turtle.write("c", font=QUIZFONT)
    turtle.setpos(375, 0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setpos(375, 180)
    turtle.penup()

    turtle.setpos(437.5, 90)
    turtle.write("d", font=QUIZFONT)
    turtle.setpos(500, 180)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setpos(0, 180)

    turtle.hideturtle()

def shapedrawer(x, y):
    global Slytherin, Griffindor, Hufflepuff, Ravenclaw

    turtle.onscreenclick(None)

    marker_turtle.penup()
    marker_turtle.setpos(x, y)
    marker_turtle.pendown()

    # First Column
    if 0 <= x <= 125 and 0 <= y <= 180:
        marker_turtle.dot(20, "green")
        Slytherin += 1
    # Second Column
    elif 125 < x <= 250 and 0 <= y <= 180:
        marker_turtle.dot(20, "red")
        Griffindor += 1
    # Third Column
    elif 250 < x <= 375 and 0 <= y <= 180:
        marker_turtle.dot(20, "purple")
        Hufflepuff += 1
    # Fourth Column
    elif 375 < x <= 500 and 0 <= y <= 180:
        marker_turtle.dot(20, "blue")
        Ravenclaw += 1

    time.sleep(5)
    marker_turtle.clear()
    marker_turtle.color("black")

    if questions:
        (questions.pop(0))()
        turtle.onscreenclick(shapedrawer)
    else:
        # here's where you display the results!
        # first erase the default turtle too.
        pass

def candy_question():
    marker_turtle.penup()
    marker_turtle.goto(100, 350)
    marker_turtle.write("""
What is your favorite type of candy?
 a. Bertie Bott's Every Flavour Beans
 b. Honeydukes Sherbet Lemons
 c. Chocolate Frogs
 d. Candy Floss""", font=TEXTFONT)

def pet_question():
    marker_turtle.penup()
    marker_turtle.goto(170, 250)
    marker_turtle.write("""
Which is animal would you prefer as a pet?
 a. A lizard
 b. A cat
 c. A dog
 d. A ferret""", font=TEXTFONT)

def class_question():
    marker_turtle.penup()
    marker_turtle.goto(170, 350)
    marker_turtle.write("""
Which is your favorite class?
 b. Potions
 a. Charms
 c. History of Magic
 d. Transfiguration""", font=TEXTFONT)

def color_question():
    marker_turtle.penup()
    marker_turtle.goto(170, 350)
    marker_turtle.write("""
Pick your favorite color:
 a. Blue
 b. Purple
 c. White
 d. Orange""", font=TEXTFONT)

def life_question():
    marker_turtle.penup()
    marker_turtle.goto(130, 350)
    marker_turtle.write("""
If you could only do one thing for the
rest of your life what would you do?
 a. Explore the World
 b. Start your own company
 c. Stay in school forever
 d. I don't know""", font=TEXTFONT)

def vacation_question():
    marker_turtle.penup()
    marker_turtle.goto(150, 250)
    marker_turtle.write("""
If you were going on a vacation,
you would go to:
 a. London
 b. The wilderness
 c. Home, to your family
 d. The beach""", font=TEXTFONT)

questions = [pet_question, class_question, color_question, life_question, vacation_question]

marker_turtle = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)

introduction()
time.sleep(5)
marker_turtle.clear()

user_interface()
(questions.pop(0))()
turtle.onscreenclick(shapedrawer)
turtle.listen()

turtle.mainloop()
```

The other key change is separate turtles for the permanent parts of the screen and those you want to erase.  I've also touched up the style a bit.  Now you need to add the final screen to display the results -- I've left a stub indicating where that might be done.